# SQL Select statement problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following `UNION`'d statement:

```
SELECT  8
UNION ALL
SELECT  7
UNION ALL
SELECT  10
```

...and a normal `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT column1
  FROM table1
```

Now my question is, how to merge the two and get the following result

```
SELECT column1, 10    -- 10 is the biggest element in the UNION statement
  FROM table1
```

Comment: Yeah,,,post your table structure and some query result..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None are particularly pretty, for the sake of returning a cartesian product:

```
SELECT t1.column1,
       (SELECT MAX(x.col)
          FROM (SELECT 8 AS col
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 7 AS col
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 10 AS col) x)
 FROM TABLE1 t1
```

The ANSI-89 approach:

```
SELECT t1.column1,
       y.max_col
  FROM TABLE1 t1,
       (SELECT MAX(x.col) AS max_col
          FROM (SELECT 8 AS col
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 7 AS col
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 10 AS col) x) y
```

The ANSI-92 approach, using CROSS JOIN (not supported on all databases):

```
    SELECT t1.column1,
           y.max_col
      FROM TABLE1 t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(x.col) AS max_col
              FROM (SELECT 8 AS col
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT 7 AS col
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT 10 AS col) x) y
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But, why they will not work when i remove the table alias?

Comment: @Yousui: Because the table alias is required??

Comment: @Yousui: SQL Server (and MySQL for that matter) **require** a table alias for a derived table.  I just do it out of habit for readability.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
SELECT column1, (SELECT MAX(v) FROM (SELECT  8 AS v
                                     UNION ALL
                                     SELECT  7 AS v
                                     UNION ALL
                                     SELECT  10 AS v
                                     ) x)
FROM   table1
```

?

Comment: I've already tried this syntax, but SQL Server give me an error:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: @zerkms: You need a table alias on the inner query (`(SELECT 8 as v .. ) t`).  Might not want to be so overly confident next time.

Comment: @mellamokb: I added a comment and added an alias in the same time. Don't be so over confident next time too, ok? Also, forgotten alias gives **another** error, so he still has a error in his query, not in my advice.

Comment: @zerkms: Sorry, didn't mean it that way.  It's just your comment came across as "Whaddya mean it doesn't work? You musta messed it up, stupid!" when in reality he found a legitimate issue with your post.  You didn't acknowledge that, and instead, accused the OP.

Comment: @mellamokb: uhm, did not want to accuse :-( Never could even imagine that mentioning that OP has a error somewhere else can accuse :-( Language and cultural issues probably...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT column1, (SELECT MAX(TABLE2.X) 
        FROM (SELECT  8 AS X UNION ALL SELECT  7 AS X UNION ALL SELECT  10 AS X) TABLE2 ) 
     AS MY_MAX
FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @Yousui, @luiscolorado: The inner query needs a table alias!!